# API to list files on a Windows Mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile, file, windows-ce

I'm writing an Windows Mobile application and I'd like to get a list of files in a certain folder on the device. Is there an API to use to read information about folders and files in the device file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be just like a desktop application would do it. For .NET have a look at [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) and similar classes.

For C++ start from [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914391.aspx)

Comment: Yes, FindFirstFile et al works fine. Don't know why I didn't realize that I can use that one on Windows Mobile as well. Thanks for the hint.